# работа с sha256managed.transformBlock в многопоточном приложении

Tags: c#, многопоточность, sha256

Имеется файл большого размера. Файл делится на блоки заданной длины. Для каждого блока вычисляется значение hash-функции *SHA256*. Вычисления должны проходить используя многопоточность с максимальной загрузкой системы. 
Каждый рассчитываемый блок по размеру может превышать оперативную память компьютера.

Как я вижу решение данной задачи. У меня есть поток, который читает данные из файла. Т.к. считать сразу весь блок невозможно, ввиду нехватки памяти, я делю его еще на несколько частей, и записываю в очередь ограниченного размера. Также у меня имеются несколько потоков которые беру эти части блока и вычисляют промежуточное значение хеша с помощью метода `TransformBlock` класса `SHA256Managed`. После того, как все части блока посчитаны, вызываем `TransformFinalBlock` и получаем хеш блока.

Проблема в том, что, как я понял, данный метод требует строгого соблюдения порядка рассчитываемых частей блока, иначе результирующее значение будет другим. Собственно это я и не знаю как обеспечить. Потоки рассчитывают части блока параллельно и выдают результат в разном порядке.

Как синхронизировать потоки чтобы они выдавали результаты в нужном порядке?

Код выполняющийся внутри потоков:

```
public class CalculatingSha256
{
    private static object lockObj = new object();
    private static SortedList sha256DataList;

    public CalculatingSha256()
    {
        sha256DataList = new SortedList();
        sha256DataList = SortedList.Synchronized(sha256DataList);
    }

    public void CalculateSha256(PartBlock block)
    {
        int index = sha256DataList.IndexOfKey(block.IdFullBlock);
        SHA256Data sha256Data = null; 

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            sha256Data = (SHA256Data)sha256DataList.GetByIndex(index);
        }

        if (sha256Data == null)
        {
            sha256Data = new SHA256Data();
            if (block.SizeFullBlock != 0)
            {
                sha256Data.BlockSize = block.SizeFullBlock;
            }
            sha256Data.Sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                sha256DataList.Add(block.IdFullBlock, sha256Data);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(block.Id+"  "+block.SizeFullBlock+"  "+block.IdFullBlock);
        sha256Data.Sha256.TransformBlock(block.Data, 0, block.Size, block.Data, 0);
        sha256Data.CurrentCalculated += block.Size;
        bool bBlockCalculateIsOver = sha256Data.CurrentCalculated == sha256Data.BlockSize;

        if ((sha256Data.BlockSize != 0) && (bBlockCalculateIsOver))
        {
            byte[] input = new byte[0];
            sha256Data.Sha256.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, 0);
            string hashString = ToString(sha256Data.Sha256.Hash);
            Console.WriteLine("Блок номер {0}:{1}", block.IdFullBlock+1, hashString.ToUpper());
            sha256DataList.Remove(block.IdFullBlock);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Block
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
}

public class PartBlock : Block
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    //номер целого блока которому принадлежит
    public int IdFullBlock { get; set; }
    public int SizeFullBlock { get; set; }
}

public class SHA256Data
{
    public int BlockSize { get; set; }
    public int CurrentCalculated { get; set; }
    public SHA256Managed Sha256 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, алгоритм SHA256 *не параллелизируется*: `TransformBlock` нужно вызывать строго по порядку, следующий после окончания предыдущего, так что распараллелить на несколько потоков не выйдет.

Имея это в виду, можно не скатываться на низкий уровень ручного вызова `TransformBlock`, а сделать просто

```
byte[] hash;
using (var fileStream = File.Open(path))
    hash = SHA256Managed.Create().ComputeHash(fileStream);
```

При этом проблемы с размером файла уходят, файловый поток будет читаться по кускам. (Вы теряете при этом сообщения о прогрессе операции, правда.)

---

Если вы и правда хотите резать файл на куски заданной длины, вы можете написать вспомогательный частичный файловый поток (не проверял):

```
class PartialFileStream : Stream
{
    public PartialFileStream(FileStream fs, long start, long length)
    {
        if (!fs.CanSeek || !fs.CanRead)
            throw new ArgumentException("Seekable and readable stream required",
                                        nameof(fs));
        this.fs = fs;
        fs.Position = start;
        this.PartStart = start;
        this.PartLength = length;
    }

    FileStream fs;
    long PartStart, PartLength;

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanSeek => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override long Length => PartLength;

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return fs.Position - PartStart; }
        set { fs.Position = value + PartStart; }
    }

    public override void Flush() => fs.Flush();

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var maxAllowedLength = PartLength - Position;
        return fs.Read(buffer, offset, (int)Math.Min(count, maxAllowedLength));
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        switch (origin)
        {
        case SeekOrigin.Begin:
            return fs.Seek(offset + PartStart, SeekOrigin.Begin) - PartStart;
        case SeekOrigin.Current:
            return fs.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Current) - PartStart;
        case SeekOrigin.End:
            return fs.Seek(offset + PartStart + PartLength, SeekOrigin.Begin) - PartStart;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(origin));
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}
```

Имея такой вспомогательный класс, дальнейшее просто:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run().Wait();
    }

    async Task Run()
    {
        var path = тут-путь-к-файлу;
        long size = new FileInfo(path).Length;
        long chunkSize = тут-размер-одного-куска;
        long nchunks = (size + chunkSize - 1) / chunkSize;
        var encodeTasks = new List<Task<byte[]>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nchunks; i++)
        {
            var length = chunkSize;
            if (i == nchunks - 1) // last chunk
                length = size - i * chunkSize;
            encodeTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ComputeHash(path, i * chunkSize, length)));
        }
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(encodeTasks);
        // тут у вас есть массив хешей, делайте с ним что-то
    }

    byte[] ComputeHash(string path, long startPos, long length)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(path))
        using (var partialStream = new PartialFileStream(fileStream, startPos, length))
            return SHA256Managed.Create().ComputeHash(partialStream);
    }
}
```

Если не хочется возиться с собственными классами потоков, можно и вручную:

```
byte[] ComputeHash(string path, long startPos, long length)
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        fs.Position = startPos;
        using (var sha = SHA256Managed.Create())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[4096];
            long bytesToGo = length;
            while (bytesToGo > 0)
            {
                var bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.Min(buffer.Length, bytesToGo));
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    throw new EndOfStreamException();
                sha.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);
                bytesToGo -= bytesRead;
            }
            sha.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);
            return sha.Hash;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Некоторые релевантные части обсуждения (полное обсуждение см. [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52351/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---sha256managed-transformblock--)):

> @PavelMayorov — Когда я делал свой `PartialStream`, я убрал у него поддержку Seek - и вышло довольно просто. В конструкторе задавалась только длина, смещение считалось от того места где поток был создан.
>
> @VladD — Думаю, не нужно ли создание внутреннего потока переложить вовнутрь, а то кто-нибудь попробует на один файловый поток надеть несколько частичных потоков с понятными последствиями.
>
> @PavelMayorov — Не думаю. Все-таки на один поток два `StreamReader` тоже навешивать одновременно нехорошо - но это же не мешает ими пользоваться.
>
> @PavelMayorov — Вообще говоря, согласно интерфейсу, `TransformBlock` возвращает сколько байт ему удалось "прожевать". Но для `HashAlgorithm` он всегда возвращает `inputCount`.
>
> @PavelMayorov — Кстати, вот еще один возможный способ. Можно создать `CryptoStream` в режиме `Write` над `NullStream` и записывать в него
>
> @redfenix — Код в потоке сначала будет нагружать диск читая из потока,а потом процессор когда будет рассчитывать хеш. Мне нужно чтобы ресурсы компьютера использовались с максимальной эффективностью.
>
> @redfenix — будет ли предложенный вариант равномерно использовать ресурсы компьютера?
>
> @VladD — Если кусков достаточно много, то будет, конечно. Но вычисление хэша от куска вы всё равно не можете распараллелить. Если вы вычисляете хеш следующего куска в новом потоке, это никак не лучше, чем вычисление в старом потоке: всё равно этим вычислением занят один поток.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52351/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---sha256managed-transformblock--).

Comment: может в ответ их добавить в PS?